# How to use scroll view in slide Menu panel

Tags: android, scrollview, android-framelayout

i am using the below layout file and it is working fine in portrait mode. it contains menu panel and sliding panel. i want to enable the landscape mode also in my application but in landscape mode the data is not appearing. so i want to put a scroll view in the below layout how can i achieve this.if i tried to put a scroll view inside the sliding panel the list view is not sliding and the screen also shrinking from bottom.

**Layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_bg"

    >

    <!-- Menu Panel -->
    <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/menuPanel"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="right"
           android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
           android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/menu_title_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" 
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"             
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="#353535"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="@string/menu_title">     
            </TextView>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_title_1"
                android:background="#b5b5b5"/>

             <ListView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_1"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
               android:id="@+id/list"
                ></ListView>
            </RelativeLayout>

       <!-- Sliding Panel -->  



        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/slidingPanel"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@android:color/white" >



                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/file"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    >

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/header_vertical_divider_1"
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menuViewButton"
                        android:background="#4d4d4d" />



                     <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/menuViewButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
                    android:onClick="slidewindow"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_menu"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                         <ImageView
                             android:id="@+id/logo"
                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                             android:src="@drawable/sislogo"
                             />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/dividerHeaderBottom"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                     />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/container" 

                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/containerheader" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        style="@style/lblstyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Name      :" 

                        />
                     <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        style="@style/lblstyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:text="Student   :"


                         />
                      <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        style="@style/lblstyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:text="Grade      :"

                         />
                      <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        style="@style/lblstyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:text="Term       :" 
                        />
                       <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        style="@style/lblstyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:text="School     :"   
                        />
                        <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name"
                        style="@style/lblstyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="name" 
                         />
                          <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/student"
                        style="@style/lblstyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:text="name" 
                        />
                           <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/grade"
                        style="@style/lblstyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/student"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:text="name"   
                        />
                            <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/term"
                        style="@style/lblstyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/grade"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:text="name"
                         />
                             <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/school"
                        style="@style/lblstyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/term"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                        android:text="name" 
                        />

                             <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/childimage"
                                android:layout_width="40dp"
                                android:layout_height="40dp"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
                                android:background="#847474"

                                />

                             <TextView
                                 android:id="@+id/textView6"
                                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                 android:text="TextView" 
                                  android:textColor="#ffffff"  />



                </RelativeLayout>



                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/newscontainer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="40"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                     android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="25dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                       android:background="@drawable/gray_bg" />
                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listView1news"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >
                    </ListView>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:text="School News"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                 <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical" 
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="bottom"

          >

          <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="30dp" 
          android:gravity="bottom"
          android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar">

          <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView3"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:src="@drawable/hom" 
           android:onClick="HOME"
           />

          <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView4"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView3"
           android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
           android:src="@drawable/logout" 
           android:onClick="Logout"
           />
         </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>






</FrameLayout>
```

how to put scrollview in the below layout file.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Hi first create a Folder layout-land and then copy your layout file in to it and now put the Scrollview for example check the code below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- The Other Elements -->
   </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: the listviews are not scrolling if i put a scrollview like this can you suggest other way